# Выдает ошибку при отправкe sql запроса

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

Есть запрос

```
$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','*********','my_db');

$sql ="INSERT INTO `projects`(`project_title`,`project_author`, `project_description`, `project_files`,`project_image`,`project_tags`) VALUES ('$project_title','$author','$project_description','?','$image_name','$tags_serialize')";

$query = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
```

Если вставить этот запрос просто в phpmyadmin все работает. А так выдает ошибку

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '$project_title','$author','$project_description','?','$image_name','$tags_serial' at line 11064
```

Comment: Зачем вы используйте '?', если дальше у вас нет bind_param?

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте изменить переменную `$sql` следующим образом:

```
$sql ="INSERT INTO projects (project_title, project_author, project_description, project_files,project_image,project_tags) 
VALUES ('$project_title','$author','$project_description','?','$image_name','$tags_serialize')";
```